# node.js create public folder which can be accessed

Tags: node.js, local

I've set up a node js server, and I'm having trouble accessing any files on my local server excluding the index.html file that I have explicitly linked to in my server.js file. How would I be able to access, for example some library files from my html page without recieving 404 errors?

Here is my file structure:

```
index.html
server.js
public/
--js/
----lib/
------ember-1.7.0.js
------ember-data.js
------handlebars-1.1.2.js
------jquery-1.10.2.js
------moment.js
------showdown.js
----router.js
```

Below is the updated content of my server.js file. The original problem was that I started working with express before I called my variables, so I didn't have access to the middleware. I still have an issue however. What am I doing wrong now?

```
/* Express 3 requires that you instantiate a `http.Server` to attach socket.io to first */
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var port = 8080;

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);

var url  = 'http://localhost:' + port + '/';
if(process.env.SUBDOMAIN){
    url = 'http://' + process.env.SUBDOMAIN + '.jit.su/';
}    

server.listen(port);
console.log(url);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + path.normalize('/index.html'));
});
```

Comment: You're just missing some middleware: http://expressjs.com/api.html#express.static

Comment: I think you're supposed to require your libraries (path, express, etc) before initializing your app. Try doing this `var expresss = require('express'), http = require('http'), path = require('path'); var app = express();`

Comment: The important thing about lascort's suggestion is it gives you access to `express`, which has middleware that you'll need to make this work.

Comment: that's exactly what I'm pointing, isn't that supposed to be that way?

Comment: @lascort it doesn't have to be, if you don't need access to express. But you almost always need access to express. :)

Comment: @kevinB Thanks for your help so far. I've updated my code above. Is that what you two had in mind, or have I made a mistake? It still is coming up with 404 errors.

Comment: @lascort, is the updated code what you meant? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @JosephAbell That is a step in the right direction, now you just need to implement the middleware in my first comment